# Package has no installation candidate(awn), but it's present in the repository

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I keep trying to install Avant Window Navigator(yes, it's old but it apparently works), from the https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8 ppa, and you can even CTRL+F and search for "Avant" and you can see it in the list of packages, but instead, I receive a 'No installation candidate' error.

Could it be that I'm on 17.04? Is there some way to get AVN on 17.04?

Comment: Did you add the `ppa` to your system?

Comment: Yes, it is because you're on 17.04: you can see that the package is not available for that release if you [filter the PPA's package list on `zesty`](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8?field.series_filter=zesty)

Comment: That seems to be the case. Oh well, downgrading is still an option.